Does the dominant science paradigm imply that we are robots?
If everything is composed of atoms and atoms make up molecules, which make up the brain, which (through interactions with other inanimate objects) cause all of your brain activity, then it would seem to imply that people of science believe that we are ultimately (complex) robots.

Who are these "people of science" to start with. And who cares what they believe? Best way to find out would be to ask them. Also, "robots" as opposed to what concept?

@tkruse:  By "people of science" I would refer to the people in mainstream publishing of science, who espouse the idea, for example, that sick people are just malfunctioning machines.  "Robots" as opposed to either divine or transcendent organic beings.  The number pi for example is transcendental to the rational numbers, for example, in that you can never express pi by a rational number (you can however appeal to it with an infinite number of them, but infinity is a transcendental concept).

So it's all meaningless new ate blabla? Why can't we be divine transcendent robots? Why would it matter that pi is not a rational number, most reals are irrational? People of science are diverse and agree on no single view of metaphysics.

The dominant scientific paradigm does not define "robots" or "zombies" or anything like that in a way to allow any assertions about humans being one or the other.
The dominant scientific paradigm asserts that humans are humans.
In philosophy of the mind, the argument from the question is typically framed using "zombies" rather then "robots", e.g. here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zombies/
The dominant scientific paradigm about the mind is that how the mind works is yet unsolved, so it could be entirely reducible to physical process (which may or may not be deterministic), or it might not be reducible. Since science has no hard proof of anything else non-reducible in any experiment, theories of mind requiring non-reducible properties are typically not the default hypothesis in dominant scientific paradigm, but rather the competing hypothesis to the default.
The SEP summarizes like this:

In spite of the fact that the arguments on both sides have become increasingly sophisticated — or perhaps because of it — they have not become more persuasive. The pull in each direction remains strong.


You start

If everything is composed of atoms and atoms make up molecules and...

This may have been valid in the heyday of science and scientism philosophers like Comte ie the 19th century, the century of a billiard ball universe, with the sunrise at Dalton, high noon at Mendeleef and sunset at Thomson's discovery of the electron.
After that it's been a complete morass:

100s of elementary particles
quarks unobservable due to color confinement
string theory “Not even wrong”
Einstein is the greatest and disagrees with pretty much every other scientist on determinism, causality etc — “God does not play dice”

Today there is quite literally no foundation to materialism in the sense that there is no accepted starting building block for ontology even physics ontology (leave aside other areas like ethics, aesthetics, religion etc).
Today anyone who professes materialism/physicalism/scientism/naturalism/positivism/etc-etc is lagging a 100 years behind the curve and that means the majority of mainstream scientists who venture into metaphysical claims.
[I always try  to distinguish scientists who stay with their detailed specializations from scientism-ists who claim access to overarching metaphysical Truth]
George Gurdjieff

...it would seem to imply that people of science believe that we are ultimately (complex) robots

George Gurdjieff who spoke extensively in thus vein, may be of interest.
Note: Gurdjieff's oeuvre was before computers else he might have used the metaphor of robot/program/computer/AI rather than machine since the “hardware” is only of secondary importance in relation to the “software” 

Man is a machine. All his deeds, actions, words, thoughts, feelings, convictions, opinions, and habits are the results of external influences, external impressions. Out of himself a man cannot produce a single thought, a single action. Everything he says, does, thinks, feels—all this happens. Man cannot discover anything, invent anything. It all happens.
To establish this fact for oneself, to understand it, to be convinced of its truth, means getting rid of a thousand illusions about man, about his being creative and consciously organizing his own life, and so on. There is nothing of this kind. Everything happens—popular movements, wars, revolutions, changes of government, all this happens. And it happens in exactly the same way as everything happens in the life of individual man. Man is born, lives, dies, builds houses, writes books, not as he wants to, but as it happens. Everything happens. Man does not love, hate, desire—all this happens


One of man's most important mistakes, one which must be remembered, is his illusion in regard to his I.
Man such as we know him, the ‘man-machine,’ the man who cannot ‘do,’ and with whom and through whom everything ‘happens,’ cannot have a permanent and single I. His I changes as quickly as his thoughts, feelings and moods, and he makes a profound mistake in considering himself always one and the same person; in reality he is always a different person, not the one he was a moment ago.
Man has no permanent and unchangeable I. Every thought, every mood, every desire, every sensation, says ‘I.’ And in each case it seems to be taken for granted that this I belongs to the Whole, to the whole man, and that a thought, a desire, or an aversion is expressed by this Whole. In actual fact there is no foundation whatsoever for this assumption. Man’s every thought and desire appears and lives quite separately and independently of the Whole. And the Whole never expresses itself, for the simple reason that it exists, as such, only physically as a thing, and in the abstract as a concept.
Man has no individual I. But there are, instead, hundreds and thousands of separate small I’s, very often entirely unknown to one another, never coming into contact, or, on the contrary, hostile to each other, mutually exclusive and incompatible. Each minute, each moment, man is saying or thinking, ‘I.’ And each time his I is different. Just now it was a thought, now it is a desire, now a sensation, now another thought, and so on, endlessly. Man is a plurality. Man’s name is legion.
Try to understand that what you usually call "I" is not I; there are many “I’s” and each “I” has a different wish. Try to verify this. You wish to change, but which part of you has this wish?


In response to the comment:

Does the fact that we do not, today, have a fundamental physical "theory of everything" imply that there is none, and that materialism is false?

Nonsense is not wrong
In philosophy we have the notion of “category error” which occurs under different guises across the board all over the place in a diverse slew of fields.
The physicist Pauli pithily discriminated between the two when he said “It's not even wrong.”
Which we (physicists) may elaborate by saying that while wrong is wrong, not even wrong is wronger than wrong but is too clueless to be of interest to physicists.
Likewise logicians talk of truth/falsity/tautology/contradiction not in respect of any formula but only of well formed formulas. ie

P → P is a tautology
P → Q will depend on the valuations of P,Q
P ∧ ¬P is a contradiction
QP¬∨PQ is a jumble and debarred at the club gate itself

Materialism is nonsense
Materialism is not wrong; its nonsense because no one, starting even from the materialists know even the base assertions. So its not even possible to have a debate.

If say a materialist M, were asked between 1800 and 1900 (Dalton's atoms to Thomson's electrons) what is the primary substrate of (physical) reality?
M could say (and likely would — see eg. Comte) atoms
In the first quarter of the 20th century, roughly from Thomson's electrons to Chadwick's neutrons, M would answer electrons, protons, neutrons (EPN).
Note: In the 20th century EPN were the "atoms" in the sense that they were the lowest down units known and imagined
For some time after say the 1950s it was likely quarks

But today there is nothing!!!
So leave aside the question of what is the bedrock of of all reality, if M only asserts: “Matter is the bedrock of physical reality”
One only has to retort: “And what is that?”
The answer is likely to be garbled nonsense or some 21st century equivalent of Johnson's kick.
In short arguing with a materialist is like a monolingual English speaker debating a monolingual Russian speaker — since they do not even know their base ontology what/where/how to even start the discussion?
The classic elaborations on these ideas are all the idealists from Plato to Berkeley to Kant and (I guess!) Hegel.
A good elaboration for current audiences is Bernardo Kastrup's Materialism is Baloney.
If I am asked my personal position I would invoke the definition of the non-dual teacher Nisargadatta Maharaj: “Matter is the limit of consciousness”
What this means is that if I hit my head on a wall I cannot fully correctly infer that There is a wall but rather that There is something that does not budge to my wishes/intentions.
By contrast if we — you and I — have a conversation, I can experience your thoughts and by inference your consciousness change in response to my inputs. And vice versa.
This does not rule out that some different being with a significantly different consciousness may be able to walk through walls [Jesus is said to have walked on water].
Of course M may say the Nisargadatta ontology is useless for doing physics.
True, but no more useless than the (nonsensical) ontology of the physicists.
To which (the typical) M will object: “Are you saying physics is useless?”
No it is very useful when used instrumentally, eg. to build power plants and atom bombs, and superconductors and killer drones and... etc etc etc.
The objection/rejection is exclusively of overarching fancy metaphysical/ontological claims.
Here M may object to the fact that I am obviously a beneficiary of the physicists' researches but I disrespect them by saying they have a nonsense ontology.
To which I would respond by saying no more disrespectful than the 19th century doyen of physics and icon of Einstein Ernst Mach.

Does the fact that we do not, today, have a fundamental physical "theory of everything" imply that there is none, and that materialism is false?

A bit long-winded for an answer to a question that must have 100 duplicates on this site, and is prone to be closed soon. (a bit of a waste, such a detailed answer might be more visible on a question that's not closed).

All of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies, and many of similar tags like philosophy-of-mind, free-will, determinism are duplicate. There is nothing original to the question.

My answer follows the dominant science paradigm, which relies on determinism concerning the item in question.

I consider a robot a smart system comprising an operating system and
a control unit with the ability to perveice, to remember, to decide
and to act in an autonomous way. Example: A Mars rover.

The individual human is determined by at least the following
factors: “our species’ evolutionary history, our own genetics, […]
the effects of our upbringing , environment, experience.” (Kevin
Mitchell: Free agents: how evolution gave us free will. 2023).
All these
factor are deterministic, even if we cannot specify the causal chains
in detail.

It is the person as a whole, who decides and acts. Not only our
conscious mental processes, which are sometimes equated with the
“I”.
The aforementioned causal factors determine how the person
decides and acts. The so called “free” will is not independent from
these factors.


It is necessary, when discussing similarities and differerences between humans and robots, to take this kind of determinism into account.

@tkruse I recommend reading the cited book by Mitchell. The quote is on p. 220.

Add that reference to your answer (ideally with a tiny summary) to improve the answer quality.

Instead of "determined", "determinist" and "determinism", I think you mean "caused, "causal" and "causality". Determinism à la Laplace is a much stronger claim and does not belong to modern science, as a matter of fact.

@Olivier5 Please let me kow how you distinguish between causality and determinism.

Determinism is the idea that, given certain initial conditions, only one outcome can happen. The outcome is fully determined by prior conditions. Causality is a loser concept, implying that certain outcomes (plural) may happen regularly as a result of certain initial conditions. E.g. "exposure to a certain virus can cause COVID 19 in some people" is different from "any one exposed to the virus will certainly get COVID 19."

@Olivier5 For you the term causality is weaker than determinism because we do not know all relevant laws of nature and all relevant boundary conditions. Hence your point is an epistemic difference. But both concepts agree in their ontological view onto the process: The past completely determines the future – not taking quantum mechanics into account.- If we agree about this point I would add it to my answer.

My point is precisely  that we do not need to assume that "the past completely determines the future" to study nature scientifically. It's not a necessary axiom for science, and in fact it contradicts modern science. Suffice to say that the past causes the future, meaning something like: it makes it happen, it engenders it, in ways that are in part predictable and understandable. Determinism cannot be described as "dominant".

@Olivier5 I see that we do not agree with each other. What about converting your comments into a separate question?

I see it as a question of fact, whether or not determinism is the dominant paradigm in biology. I don't think it is.

I suspect that your question contains a lot of implied "just": "humans just robots", "everything just atoms".  This indicates to me that you take issue with the aesthetics of the materialist position on mind.
I think that one can also take Carl Sagan's attitude that "We are made of star-stuff. We are a way for the universe to know itself."  Far from being "just atoms", you are made of seven billion billion billion atoms, most of which spent time blazing in a star that was our sun's ancestor.  Those seven billion billion billion atoms are arranged into a most complex and intricate dance, all working together to form the ribonucleic acids that are the blueprints and the lipids and proteins that are the bricks of each of the 30 trillion cells that comprise "you".  These cells are of hundreds of unique types, and engage in their own complex and intricate dance.  This complex and intricate dance, as far as we know, is unique in all the universe in being able to build telescopes and microscopes and to look through them to watch itself dancing.  Literally millions of humans have dedicated their entire lives to investigating this dance within a dance within a dance, and to designing and building these tools so that you can just sit back and watch the dance with the clearest view possible.
So, I guess, one can either choose to enjoy watching the dance which, nowadays, we can literally see, or... not?  I suppose the dance will go on with or without your applause.  IMHO, if the decision to be made is purely an aesthetic one, then the materlialist position is actually one of the more agreeable ones, especially if one actually takes the time to learn details of the modern state of scientific knowledge and the scientific process underpinning it.

The scientism project, of collapsing everything in our universe down to a physics explanation, is still pursued by some, but this is now a very minority view in philosophy.
Science itself cannot be reduced to science, as it relies upon philosophy to justify it.
Science requires abstractions in order to be done.  Logic, math, ideas.  these have no mass, energy, or location.  Science itself is not material.
Science has accepted emergence as a minimum as a supplemental framework in characterizing our world, in addition to reductionism.  Versions of emergent physicalism are the primary concepts pursued by philosophers of mind, rather than purely reductive models.
Additionally, holism, and process physics provide two more frameworks that also challenge reductionism.
So while a purely reductive materialism would say we humans are robots, science-oriented physicalist philosophy has expanded its conceptual space with the inclusion of abstractions, and emergence, and holism, and process physics.  HOW a non-robot might be accommodated with this more complex framework is still a TBD, but scientific philosophy has not conceded that this could never be accomplished.
For a reference on reductionism, and its abandonment by philosophy as unachievable in its globalist version, see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/, most specifically section 5, where the failures of global reductionism as a program and subsequent abandonment are spelled out. For the rejection of scientism and acceptance of other sources of knowledge, see https://iep.utm.edu/sci-ideo/#H6, most specifically section 6, where the limits of science are explicitly argued.

@tkruse It is your personal esoteric belief which has been rejected by philosophy.  That is clear in your own link on reductionism, which spells out how two-way interaction is a key principle of it, and how a tiered structure is now standard thinking in science, and is evidenced.  But you did prompt me to add links showing explicitly that philosophy has rejected your global reductionist scientism.

@tkruse Please try to focus on refuting the argument and not directing criticisms at the person. Your first comment above is an interesting contribution but the last sentence about him “pushing personal beliefs” isn’t necessary; Dcleve has done a good job of laying out his viewpoint and citing sources to support it.

@tkruse -- Your own reference refutes your claims.  Every section in it includes assertions of Irreducibility in principle, contrary to your assertion that weak emergence, and ultimate reductive explanation in the future is all there is.

@tkruse  Your own reference disagrees with you once more;  Weak Emergence: This type of emergence involves properties that can in principle be derived from the interactions of lower-level entities but are not immediately obvious.

@tkruse -- my answer uncontroversially outlines the conceptual space that is accepted by a consensus of philosophers of science, and includes the reasons materialism has been abandoned in favor of physicalism, the limitations of science, scientific and global pluralism, strong emergence, and allows for the dominant ontology among philosophers today of non-reductive physicalism.  There are no "issues" with my answer.  It is only "controversial" for the very small minority remaining of global reductionists.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Since the question is closed anyway, I'll just delete all my other comments and explain my downvote without further discussion: Weak emergence is no addition to reductionism. Strong emergence is not accepted by science, it it practically anti-scientific (having zero proof of existence). See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergentism . Emergentism in contemporary science and mainstream philosophy relies on reductionism, the specifics of reduction however are still fluid in philosophy such as allowing attributes of smaller entities to be reduceable to integration or structure of the whole.

@tkruse As I have repeatedly pointed out to you, your reference disagrees absolutely with your claims about it.  Evidence for irreducibility are cited there.  and science operates with reduction as a critically useful heuristic, but does not require GLOBAL reduction.  The other three non-reductive heuristics I noted are all useful in scientific inquiry.    Your now arguing on two explicitly contrary sides of what "weak reductionism" consists of -- I will let you and others contemplate.
